# Save user info in HTML python anywhere

Tags: python, html, database, django, userform

I am making my first django web app.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head><style>
body{
    text-align:center;
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/qv9As5Y.jpg");
    color: black;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
p{
    font-size:24px;
}
input {
    border: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background:limegreen;
    color:black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- I'm a comment. You won't actually see me on the web page.
     You should write your header in the line below me! -->


<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iAX7FpC.png" height="250" width="250">

<h1>Joe Buty</h1>
<h1>Data Science</h1>


<h2>    Hello,</h2>

<h3><p>    Welcome to my webpage. If you are reading this you might be the
first person to visit my website. So thanks.</p>
<p>    This page is constantly evolving.</p>


<h2>    <p>So if you would like to be in the loop enter your email. Thanks!</p>

<input type='email' placeholder="Email">
<input type='submit'> <!This button needs to do something!>
</body>
```

There is a submit email button that I made while doing the create your page demo in the codecademy tutorial. The problem is now that I actually want to save the user info to a database I am not sure how.

I am going to work and probably solve this problem, but if you can offer me any guidance I would appreciate it!

Let me know if you have any questions about my question.

cheers

Comment: You should check out the Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: It seems like you should do more tutorials, and if you have a *specific* problem, then ask it on this site.

Comment: @mikesmithDev I did ask a specific question. how to i get my button to store info into a database!

Comment: @Reverend_Dude that is not a question that can be answered in a few paragraphs. My close vote was for "Too Broad" (not "unclear"), as asking how to save to a database *isn't* specific. It is very broad. Specific would be "why is this INSERT statement failing". If the answer is "go do a tutorial or read a book", then the question probably isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please review [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to get a better idea why it was closed.

Comment: Ahh Ok Thanks Mike, I will continue to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you have a website it is a good idea to save user info in a database. 
There are many ways to do this; the most popular of which is SQL.
If you are interested in learning more, check out this class https://www.udacity.com/course/cs253

Comment: Thanks! I will check that out and let you know if I get it working